# Java Program says that sound file is not there

Tags: java, swing, audio

I am currently coding a piano in Java and I used to have an entire class where, when a note was pressed a specific method in that class was called that specific note. In order to shorten my code (Still working on that part), I used the integers of the `boolean` array that I made to decide the note. For example, if `boolean[1]` was set to `true`, I'd call the method with the integer and based on that integer, a string would be set to the name of the sound file. The problem I am having is that it constantly says the file is not there, and I know for a fact it is. Can someone help me out here?

```
import java.awt.event.*; //imports
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;


public class PianoGame extends JFrame{ //JFrame class
    public PianoGame(){
        super("PianoGame");
        setSize(1000,600);
        setLocation(400,50);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        PianoGameContent pgb = new PianoGameContent();
        setContentPane(pgb);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        PianoGame pg  = new PianoGame();
    }
}
class PianoGameContent extends JPanel implements KeyListener { //JPanel Class
    boolean[] notes = new boolean [30];
    File [] snotes = new File [30];

    public PianoGameContent() {
        boolean[] notes = new boolean [30];
        Arrays.fill(notes, Boolean.FALSE);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 50); //draw Piano
        g.setFont(f);
        for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++){
            if(notes[i] == true){
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(50*i, 200, 50, 300);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                play(i);
            }
            else{
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(50*i, 200, 50, 300);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 1; i<18; i++)
        g.drawRect(50*i, 200, 50, 300);

        if (notes[18] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(85, 200, 30, 175);
            play(18);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(85, 200, 30, 175);
        }

        if (notes[19] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(135, 200, 30, 175);
            play(19);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(135, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[20] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(235, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(235, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[21] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(285, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(285, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[22] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(335, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(335, 200, 30, 175);
        }

        if (notes[23] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(435, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(435, 200, 30, 175);
        }

        if (notes[24] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(485, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(485, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[25] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(585, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(585, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[26] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(635, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(635, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[27] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(685, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(685, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[28] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(785, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(785, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        if (notes[29] == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(835, 200, 30, 175);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(835, 200, 30, 175);
        }
        g.drawRect(85, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(135, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(235, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(285, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(335, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(435, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(485, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(585, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(635, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(685, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(785, 200, 30, 175);
        g.drawRect(835, 200, 30, 175);

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //keypress sets assigned variable to true
        char x;
        x = e.getKeyChar();
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1)
            notes [18] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2)
            notes [19] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_3)
            notes [20] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_4)
            notes [21] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_5)
            notes [22] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_6)
            notes [23] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_7)
            notes [24] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_8)
            notes [25] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_9)
            notes [26] = true;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_0)
            notes [27] = true;
        if (x == 'q')
            notes [1] = true;
        if (x == 'w')
            notes [2]= true;
        if (x == 'e')
            notes [3] = true;
        if (x == 'r')
            notes [4] = true;
        if (x == 't')
            notes [5] = true;
        if (x == 'y')
            notes [6] = true;
        if (x == 'u')
            notes [7] = true;
        if (x == 'i')
            notes[8] = true;
        if (x == 'o')
            notes[9] = true;
        if (x == 'p')
            notes[10] = true;
        if (x == 'a')
            notes [11] = true;
        if (x == 's')
            notes [12] = true;
        if (x == 'd')
            notes [13] = true;
        if (x == 'f')
            notes [14] = true;
        if (x == 'g')
            notes [15] = true;
        if (x == 'h')
            notes [16] = true;
        if (x == 'j')
            notes [17] = true;
        if (x == 'k')
            notes [28]= true;
        if (x == 'l')
            notes [29] = true;
        repaint();

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { //when released everything gets reset to false
        Arrays.fill(notes, Boolean.FALSE);
        repaint();
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void play(int decide){
        String x = "c4.wav";
        if (decide == 1)
            x = "c4.wav";
        if (decide == 2)
            x = "d4.wav";
        if (decide == 3)
            x = "e4.wav";
        if (decide == 4)
            x = "f4.wav";
        if (decide == 5)
            x = "g4.wav";
        if (decide == 6)
            x = "a4.wav";
        if (decide == 7)
            x = "b4.wav";
        if (decide == 8)
            x = "c5.wav";
        if (decide == 9)
            x = "d5.wav";
        if (decide == 10)
            x = "e5.wav";
        if (decide == 11)
            x = "f5.wav";
        if (decide == 12)
            x = "g5.wav";
        if (decide == 13)
            x = "a5.wav";
        if (decide == 14)
            x = "b5.wav";
        if (decide == 15)
            x = "c6.wav";
        if (decide == 16)
            x = "d6.wav";
        if (decide == 17)
            x = "e6.wav";
        if (decide == 18)
            x = "db4.wav";
        if (decide == 19)
            x = "eb4.wav";

        try {
            File csound = new File(x);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(csound));
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `System.err.println(e.getMessage());` to `e.printStackTrace();` and **copy/paste** (rather than paraphrase) the output. As an aside: 1) If using samples for notes, load them all at start-up rather than when needed. 2) But this seems like a job for MIDI. It will be possibly to use instrument banks that are already available to the Java MIDI system.

Comment: you dont have to put up the whole code to the question just put the part where you are getting the errors . no need of the design part.

Comment: Some idea of where the files are stored in relationship to your project would also help, at the moment, your code expects them to be located within the same directory that the code is executed from, this is not the same location as class files, so beware of that

Comment: I figured it out it was just as @MadProgrammer said. I forgot the /src at the beginning of each string. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also having another problem where if you were to hold a key down it would keep playing. Is there anyway to make it so that when you hold a key down it doesn't keep acting as a key press and make it so that it waits till the key actually resets?

Comment: Adding /src is symptom of your problem, you should never reference the src in your code, instead you'll,need to use Class#getResource instead

Comment: The basic process is to set a flag when the key is pressed and reset it when it's released

Comment: Is there anything that can be done to change that or is that an OS function based thing?